# How in "update() slot" in qt5 select the area (portion) where to do paint

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5, signals-slots

I am using QT5 and want to know how to use "update() slot" to select specific AREA which get update when we give signal. I am using a checkbox, whenever we select the Checkbox, 2 leds glow (in my case), but I want to glow only 1 led. I am thinking that update() slot is selecting two leds but I want to select only 1 led. But I am not able to find how to do that (through code or qt design).

Comment: Probably your checkbox checked signal, is connected to a slot that glow two led for you. And you should edit that slot. please attach some part of code that is related to problem to receiving more useful answers.

Comment: By giving some argument to  "update() slot" can i decide where to paint ??.

Comment: Yes and no. There are overloaded update() functions that work in a specified area, but I'm not sure this is going to work for you (and it would be a maintenance issue, too). I'd be interested in seeing your slot that repaints the LEDs.